# Apartment gem - Adding current database to all server logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, server, apartment-gem

I am using the Apartment gem to switch the tenant (database) being used for a multi tenancy Rails application.

In my server logs I would like to output the current tenant (database) being used for every single line in the log file.

When I do `rails s` the server never actually starts with the code below that is in the initializers directory. The server just hangs... so odd. No error message and no running server. If I take out `#{Apartment::Tenant.current}` below everything is fine... but... I really want to know the current tenant (database) in my log files.

/initializers/log_formatting.rb:

```
class ActiveSupport::Logger::SimpleFormatter 
  def call(severity, time, progname, msg)
    "#{Apartment::Tenant.current} #{msg.strip} (pid:#{$$})\n"
  end
end
```

Any ideas on how to get the current tenant (database) being used output to every line of my log file?

Thank you!

Comment: Hey, I think the answer may be inside the current method, can you paste the code of the method ?

Comment: Are you using subdomain or a custom elevator for the tenant switch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to use `log_tags`.
From the [rails documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html) :

> config.log_tags accepts a list of: methods that the request object responds to, a Proc that accepts the request object, or something that responds to to_s. This makes it easy to tag log lines with debug information like subdomain and request id - both very helpful in debugging multi-user production applications.

You can add this configuration in application.rb or production.rb whichever fits your need.

For ex: `config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :request_id, lambda { |request| request.headers["tenant_name"] } ]`

Note: In case you are adding this for development environment and you are running on `your_subdomain.localhost:3000` then subdomain won't be present as localhost doesn't support subdomains. There are some workarounds like modifying /etc/hosts file but i won't recommend it. The more cleaner solution is to use `your_subdomain.lvh.me:3000`

Comment: subdomain doesnt appear to do anything... but it is really what I want... would solve my problem but there is no output for it.

Comment: Did you restart your server? I checked it in my local and its working fine for me. If its isn't working for you then you can always customise it using lambda as given in example.

Comment: yes. restarted server. Added your exact code above. Not getting the subdomain though.

Comment: [c2375bdf-efcb-4eb6-b064-1856b1c38f67]   ConversationsPerson Load (1.4ms)  SELECT `conversations_people`.* FROM `conversations_people` WHERE `conversations_people`.`person_id` = 24
[c2375bdf-efcb-4eb6-b064-1856b1c38f67]   Person Load (2.4ms)  SELECT `people`.* FROM `people`
[607c0a29-a913-4e15-b9ae-fccf2a29b304] Started GET "/conversations/show_for_cust_service.json" for ::1 at 2018-10-15 14:18:13 -0400
[607c0a29-a913-4e15-b9ae-fccf2a29b304]    (0.2ms)  use `iApp1_development`
[607c0a29-a913-4e15-b9ae-fccf2a29b304]    (0.1ms)  use `aba`

Comment: looks like request_id is in there... but no subdomain

Comment: This is strange. Anyways you can use
config.log_tags = [ :request_id, lambda { |request| request.subdomain } ]. This should work.

Comment: With your new code I am still not seeing subdomain. added it to development.rb and restarted server

Comment: [ffeb390d-c338-46af-8437-2f6d2ff0eed8]    (0.6ms)  SELECT `report_results`.`data` FROM `report_results` WHERE `report_results`.`report_run_id` = 2
[ffeb390d-c338-46af-8437-2f6d2ff0eed8]    (0.9ms)  SELECT `report_results`.`data` FROM `report_results` WHERE `report_results`.`report_run_id` = 4
[ffeb390d-c338-46af-8437-2f6d2ff0eed8] Completed 200 OK in 580ms (Views: 116.9ms | ActiveRecord: 77.0ms)


[ffeb390d-c338-46af-8437-2f6d2ff0eed8]    (0.3ms)  use `iApp1_development`

Comment: I definitely have a subdomain too. I am hitting this url: http://aba.localhost:3000/dashboards/

Comment: Also, I don't see :subdomain in https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html which I believe (reading more, Google more) ... I am trying :original_fullpath which I do in in ActionDispatch/Request

Comment: Okay now i see. You cannot add subdomains on localhost. You need to use aba.lvh.me:3000/dashboards

Comment: Yeah so using [:original_url] does show the subdomain locally. But I wish I could JUST show the subdomain... :original_url is too much info really

Comment: Kindly mark this answer as accepted if it solves the question. This way it will help anyone who get stuck at same point. Thanks :)